# Add normal distribution curve to histogram R

Tags: r, histogram

I'm trying to overlay a normal distribution curve onto a histogram in R. I know it's a question that's been asked before, but I'm having trouble getting the solutions to work for me.

This is my code:

```
hist(input_data$"X109_scalesraw_23", freq = TRUE, breaks = 30, 
     col = "cadetblue", xlim = c(0,30), ylim = c(0,150), 
     main = "023", xlab = "score")
```

Comment: How are you having trouble? It would be helpful if you could edit your post with a description of what's going wrong.

Comment: does it have to be base r graphics or is ggplot2 ok too?

Comment: A standard histogram and a probability density curve have very different y-axis scales. The former displays frequency whereas the latter displays density values. You might want to set `freq = FALSE` in your `hist` call, to ensure that it displays density values.

Answer (score 5):

You can always use `curve` with `add=TRUE` (telling R to add the curve to existing plot):

```
data <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
hist(data, freq = FALSE)
x<-seq(-4,+4,by=0.02)
curve(dnorm(x), add=TRUE)
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Hi all, firstly, thanks for the answers so far.

Comment: Hi all, firstly, thanks for the answers so far.

The trouble is this: I simply can't add a normal curve... The data I'm working with are test results. Each candidate has answered several questions pertaining to scale_23 and thus has a collated raw average score that includes decimal points. There are over 500 candidates in the data so the rawdata results are pretty much continuous.

Comment: I am checking through the data to create a normgroup with which I can compare later individual test results. Therefore I at the moment want to check to see if the data I have is normally distributed, which, theoretically, it ought to be. 

I can look at the histogram and make an educated guess, but for the sake of showing my bosses (and for me, yes) I want to add a normal curve "on top" of the histogram. 

I am new to R. I have not used ggplots. I am not familiar with density histograms. The scores were averaged for each scale so there are no discrete values.

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean by "I simply can't add a normal curve" - why not? If you're not sure the data is normal, there are tests that can tell you whether the data is (reasonably) normal: Jarque-Bera, Shapiro-Wilk etc. You need to show your data and show some code, then it'll be possible to give some definite answer.